# Is there any way to set pixel values of background to 0 when rendering?

Tags: rendering, light

I want to set bg pixel values to 0 (black) but when I change the color of world, the pixel values of bg become more than 1 due to lights. When disabling lights, rendered image gets plain black image including my object. I am using blender 2.8.

Is there any way to set pixel values of background to 0 when rendering?

EDIT
I'm not using any effect on the world.
The rendered image background looks plain black but when checking it with python, it's not.

[image]

[image]

Here's the rounded 1s distribution. the white pixels were 1s.

[image]

Comment: To have a completely black world, just disconnect all nodes in the world section. The lights will not light the world though. Are you using volumétrica (smoke, haze, fog or bloom)?

Comment: I don't know PIL, but so many (maybe) white parts should be visible. There can be rounded values in png format, try to export as exr (looseless) format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@no-can-do](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203395/is-there-any-way-to-set-pixel-values-of-background-to-0-when-rendering#comment341957_203395) mentioned in the comments, you would have to go in the world part of the shader editor.

If you want to keep your environment light you can use a setting like the following.

*"Is camera ray"* will drive the background color.

If it is a ray from the camera (rendered), the value is 1 and the *"mix color"* will give black.

If it is not the value is 0, the ray will be from the texture and will light the scene.

[image]

Note: if you're not using accurate texture format (openEXR), you may have rounded RGB values (i.e: 0.000something becomes 1).

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I manually changed the rounded 1s to 0 in png because I'm not familliar with exr file. :)